# How do I check a set of numbers in different columns against numbers in different columns?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting

I am trying to make a Lotto checklist in Google sheets. I have my own numbers in 6 columns, A2:F5. And I have typed the winning numbers in H2:M2, 6 columns also, with 1000 rows.
Now I want to check if my numbers in A2:F5 have any two or more of it's numbers present in the winning numbers in H2:M2(1000 rows). And if there is a match, highlight the matched cell in red background and white text using conditional formatting, custom formula.

[image]

Comment: Please [edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/169194/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of a _reasonable_ number of sample data rows together with another table that shows your _manually entered_ desired results. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Comment: While adding an image migh help, it's in questions about formulas it's better to add sample input data and the corresponding expected result as text. Please read the links included in the previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

With the 999 sets of winning numbers in the range `A2:F` and the sets of your own numbers in the range `H2:M10`, put this formula in cell `O1` (in *row 1*):

```
=let( 
  myNumbers, H2:M10, 
  winningNumbers, A2:F, 
  blank, { iferror(1/0), iferror(1/0) }, 
  { 
    { "matches", "best match to winning row #" }; 
    byrow( 
      myNumbers, 
      lambda( 
        myRow, 
        if( 
          count(myRow) = columns(myNumbers), 
          query( 
            byrow( 
              winningNumbers,
              lambda( 
                winningRow, 
                if( 
                  count(winningRow) = columns(winningNumbers), 
                  let( 
                    numWins, arrayformula(sum(countif(myRow, winningRow))), 
                    if( 
                      numWins >= 2, 
                      { numWins, row(winningRow) }, 
                      blank 
                    ) 
                  ), 
                  blank 
                ) 
              ) 
            ), 
            "order by Col1 desc limit 1", 0 
          ), 
          blank 
        ) 
      ) 
    ) 
  } 
)
```

The formula will find the winning rows that have two or more matches to your own row, choose among those winning rows the one that has the most matches, and show the number of matches and row number of that winning row.

When there is no winning row with two or more matches, the formula will show a blank.

The "best match to winning row #" column will show the spreadsheet row number rather than the ordinal number of the winning row.

| winning |  |  |  |  |  |  | mine |  |  |  |  |  |  | matches | best match to winning row # |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |  | 22 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 |  | 2 | 3 |
| 44 | 22 | 33 | 55 | 66 | 11 |  | 6 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 |  | 6 | 2 |
| 79 | 15 | 36 | 70 | 13 | 62 |  | 10 | 11 | 1 | 2 | 14 | 15 |  | 2 | 2 |
| 8 | 79 | 99 | 30 | 47 | 9 |  | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 |  |  |  |
| 57 | 81 | 42 | 68 | 86 | 95 |  | 99 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |  | 3 | 5 |
| 11 | 58 | 8 | 38 | 26 | 62 |  | 24 | 75 | 62 | 57 | 8 | 98 |  | 2 | 7 |
| 58 | 95 | 45 | 76 | 82 | 62 |  | 14 | 81 | 98 | 29 | 84 | 19 |  |  |  |
| 27 | 56 | 55 | 95 | 59 | 82 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 71 | 13 | 11 | 60 | 63 | 55 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 72 | 24 | 14 | 88 | 55 | 7 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 39 | 89 | 76 | 16 | 50 | 87 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 56 | 50 | 22 | 70 | 23 | 89 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

To highlight the numbers in your own rows that are included in the best matching winning row, use this [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) custom formula rule for the range `H2:M10`:

```
=countif( filter($A$2:$F, row($A$2:$F) = $P2), H2 )
```